# GitHub API (v3): Order tags by creation date

Tags: github, github-api

I ran into a problem / question while using the GitHub API.

I need a list of all tags created after a single tag. The only way to do this, is to compare the tags by date. However, the results from the API aren't ordered by date:

Result from the API (rails repository example):

[image: API results]

Results from the webinterface:

[image: Webinterface results]

What i did expect is a list ordered by date. However, as you can see in the pictures: the API is returning v4.0.0rc1 & v4.0.0rc2 before the release of v4.0.0, while 4.0.0 is released after the release candidates. There isn't even a creation / commit date to order at server side.

The releases API isn't a solution either. This API is only returning releases created by Github, not the releases created by tags.

Is there any way to order the tags by date?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Repositories API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-tags) currently returns tags in the order they would be returned by the "git tag" command, which means they are alphabetically sorted.

The problem with sorting tags chronologically in Git is that there are two types of tags, lightweight and annotated), and for the lightweight type Git doesn't store the creation date.

The Releases/Tags UI currently sorts tags chronologically by the date of the commit to which the tag points to. This again isn't the date on which the tag itself was created, but it does establish a chronological order of things.

Adding this alternative sorting option to the API is on our feature request list.

---

[Here](https://github.com/namgivu/tel4vnTOYA04/blob/main/s24_api/s99_github_api_w_auth_token.py) is sample code for those who need to get github tag created_at time

Comment: Something new here? It would be great get the tags sorting by date :)

Comment: unfortunately no sorting avaiable in REST calls till now

Comment: still no sorting possible today 2023

Answer (score 8):

With [GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/), we can now filter tags by commit date with `field: TAG_COMMIT_DATE` inside `orderBy`. The following will perform ascending sort of tags by commit date :

```graphql
{
  repository(owner: "rails", name: "rails") {
    refs(refPrefix: "refs/tags/", last: 100, orderBy: {field: TAG_COMMIT_DATE, direction: ASC}) {
      edges {
        node {
          name
          target {
            oid
            ... on Tag {
              message
              commitUrl
              tagger {
                name
                email
                date
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Test it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?variables=%7B%7D&query=%7B%0A%20%20repository(owner%3A%20%22rails%22%2C%20name%3A%20%22rails%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20refs(refPrefix%3A%20%22refs%2Ftags%2F%22%2C%20last%3A%20100%2C%20orderBy%3A%20%7Bfield%3A%20TAG_COMMIT_DATE%2C%20direction%3A%20ASC%7D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20oid%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Tag%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20message%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20commitUrl%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tagger%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20email%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20date%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Here, the `tagger` field inside `target` will only be filled for annotated tag & will be empty for lightweight tags.

As `date` property in `tagger` gives the creation date of the tag (for annotated tag only), it's possible to filter by creation date on the client side easily (without having to retrieve all the tags 1 by 1)

Note that available options for `orderBy.field` at this time are `TAG_COMMIT_DATE` & `ALPHABETICAL` (no `TAG_CREATION_DATE`)

Answer (score 3):

Edit: This is now possible using the [GitHub GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/).

As workaround, there is a node module for this,
which basically fetches the commit details of each tag:
[github-api-tags-full](https://github.com/strarsis/github-api-tags-full)

```
> npm install github-api-tags-full github moment

var GitHubApi  = require('github'),
moment     = require('moment'),
githubTags = require('github-api-tags-full');

var github = new GitHubApi({
  version: '3.0.0'
});

githubTags({ user: 'golang', repo: 'go' }, github)
.then(function(tags) {
  var tagsSorted = tags.sort(byAuthorDateAsc).reverse(); // descending
  console.log(tagsSorted); // prints the array of tags sorted by their creation date
});

var byAuthorDateAsc = function(tagA, tagB) {
  return githubCompareDates(
    tagA.commit.author.date,
    tagB.commit.author.date
  );
};
var githubCompareDates = function(dateStrA, dateStrB) {
  return moment(dateStrA).diff(dateStrB);
};
```

With best regards

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Git References API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/refs).

This can return also all the tags matching a certain prefix.

In you case, you probably want something like:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/rails/rails/git/matching-refs/tags/v
```

Or in the case of a monorepo:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/grafana/loki/git/matching-refs/tags/helm-loki-
```

**Downsides**:

- **sorting**: the results are sorted in increasing [semver](https://semver.org/) order and you will get the oldest first.
- you don't get much info about each tag and you might have to parse the versions out of the ref name/path

**Upside**

- you get all the ref/tags that match (i.e. no pagination, until GitHub decides to remove/optimise this :) )
- you can use it to filter out tags in a monorepo (that most probably tag release components with prefixed tags)

Answer (score 0):

to avoid graphQL, you can parse the github html
for example of https://github.com/rails/rails/tags

```bash
repo=rails/rails

curl -s "https://github.com/$repo/tags" |
grep -oE \
-e ' href="/'"$repo"'/releases/tag/[^"]+" data-' \
-e ' datetime="[^"]+"' \
-e ' href="/'"$repo"'/commit/[0-9a-f]{40,}"' |
cut -d'"' -f2 |
sed -E 's,^.*/(commit|releases/tag)/,,' |
while read name && read time && read hash; do
  echo "$time $hash $name"
done
```