# git ls-remote --tags: how to get date information?

Tags: git, git-tag, git-ls-remote

I am using `git ls-remote --tags <url>` to get the tags from a repository. However, it doesn't provide any date information. So I wonder if there is any way to get tags with date information without cloning the whole repository. I already check the git ls-remote [documents](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html),but I couldn't find any useful information. 
I tried `git ls-remote --tags https://github.com/shopify/sarama`, and I got:

```
2ed98903c79815c54f80ab06167a74755e74348c        refs/tags/v1.0.0
3b6fa677e9395c3d7151999974d1b5b36f6ac091        refs/tags/v1.1.0
9bb4a68d57ff6f623363aa172f0a8297aa289ba7        refs/tags/v1.10.0
bd61cae2be85fa6ff40eb23dcdd24567967ac2ae        refs/tags/v1.10.1
0fb560e5f7fbcaee2f75e3c34174320709f69944        refs/tags/v1.11.0
c01858abb625b73a3af51d0798e4ad42c8147093        refs/tags/v1.12.0
bbdbe644099b7fdc8327d5cc69c030945188b2e9        refs/tags/v1.13.0
240fd146ce68bcafb034cc5dc977229ffbafa8ea        refs/tags/v1.14.0
3b1b38866a79f06deddf0487d5c27ba0697ccd65        refs/tags/v1.15.0
f7be6aa2bc7b2e38edf816b08b582782194a1c02        refs/tags/v1.16.0
35324cf48e33d8260e1c7c18854465a904ade249        refs/tags/v1.17.0
a6144ae922fd99dd0ea5046c8137acfb7fab0914        refs/tags/v1.18.0
ec843464b50d4c8b56403ec9d589cf41ea30e722        refs/tags/v1.19.0
fcf765a8b80c7b3a5ba1cb3bb9036261502b1ee8        refs/tags/v1.2.0
...
```

Obviously, they are not sorted by date. Anyone can solve this problem?

According to Vonc's answer below, I find a way to get tag info ordered by date. First, use [GraphQL Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/graphql/overview/explorer) and then type the script below:

```
query{
      repository(name: "snappy", owner: "golang") {
        refs(refPrefix: "refs/tags/", orderBy: {field: TAG_COMMIT_DATE, direction: DESC}, last: 100) {
          nodes {
            name
            target {
              __typename
              ... on Tag {
                oid
                name
                tag_message: message
                tagger {
                  email
                  name
                }
                target {
                  oid
                }
              }
              ... on Commit {
                commit_message: message
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Then, you can get info ordered by commit_date DESC. Also, you can change 'DESC' to 'ASC' to reverse the result. I test this in my postman, settings are as below:
url: https://api.github.com/graphql 
method: POST
header: Authorization: bearer (my github token)
json_data:

```
{
    "query": "query{repository(name: \"snappy\", owner: \"golang\") {refs(refPrefix: \"refs/tags/\", orderBy: {field: TAG_COMMIT_DATE, direction: DESC}, last: 100) { nodes { name target { __typename ... on Tag { oid name tag_message: message tagger { email name } target { oid } } ... on Commit { commit_message: message}}}}}}"
    }
```

The info you can get is just the same with what you get from graphql explorer.

Comment: The author date and committer date are stored in commit objects and tag objects. Git does not provide a method to retrieve these data remotely. Where is your repository hosted? The hosting service may have some query method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58614437/7976758: Dates from tags and commits are only available locally. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-ls-remote%5D+sort

Comment: As you use Github you can use Github API to list references: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/git#list-matching-references and filter the results for tags. But even this API doesn't return dates, you need to get dates with additional API calls.

Comment: @phd I agree with phd because I read [github.com api documents](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/git#tags) this morning. Like using ·https://api.github.com/repos/shopify/sarama/tags· api, I can only get several tags without date information.

Comment: @ElpieKay I mainly focus on some golang repository in github.com. Thus, I guess the only solution would be to git clone the repo.

Comment: @Rick.X Do you mean a script executing a graphql query is not possible?

Comment: @VonC Maybe, I am trying.

Comment: @Rick.X For postman, you can follow https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/35240/TVCe39MD

Answer (score 6):

One strategy you can use is to make a temporary checkout and only pull the commit objects down (ignoring the blobs and the rest of the commits).

```sh
git init repo
cd repo
git config extensions.partialClone true
git remote add origin https://github.com/shopify/sarama
time git fetch --filter=blob:none --tags --depth=1 origin
git tag -l | xargs -t -n1 git log --format=%cd
```

in the case of the repository listed in the original post the clone is very small (the fetch also took less than a second):

```
$ du -hs .
504K    .
```

```
$ git tag -l | xargs -t -n1 git log --format=%cd |& head -10
git log '--format=%cd' v1.0.0 
Tue Mar 17 13:48:54 2015 -0400
git log '--format=%cd' v1.1.0 
Fri Mar 20 19:21:21 2015 +0000
git log '--format=%cd' v1.10.0 
Tue Aug 2 08:43:06 2016 -0400
git log '--format=%cd' v1.10.1 
Tue Aug 30 09:25:53 2016 -0400
git log '--format=%cd' v1.11.0 
Tue Dec 20 13:06:16 2016 -0500
```

Comment: IMHO the best answer as it relies only on git and not some hoster API

Comment: in current version of git docs there is no `--filter` option for `git fetch` but there is for `git clone`

Comment: @rychu probably an oversight -- almost all of the clone options are forwarded to the sub-implementations of `init`, `remote add`, `fetch`, and `checkout` which make up `clone`

Comment: @AnthonySottile ok, but also, maybe `git clone -q --filter=blob:none --no-checkout <url>` can be used instead of git init + git remote add + git fetch

Comment: @rychu that pulls in all the heads which is more than just the tags

Answer (score 3):

Here's this feature that I recently got to know (thanks to my mentor).
GitHub [supports subversion](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/working-with-subversion-on-github/support-for-subversion-clients), a part of it at least.
So, you can do

```
svn --verbose ls https://github.com/nexB/vulnerablecode/tags
```

Comment: You might have meant `svn --verbose ls https://github.com/nexB/vulnerablecode/tags` or `svn --xml ls https://github.com/nexB/vulnerablecode/tags` ?

Answer (score 0):

The only option, without any clone, would be to use a [GraphQL API v4](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/graphql), in order to filter tags by commit date with field: `TAG_COMMIT_DATE` inside `orderBy`, as seen in

- "[GitHub API (v3): Order tags by creation date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47501956/6309)"
- "[Github GraphQl - How to get a list of commits between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56401516/6309)

Each time, you would start the query with:

```
refs(refPrefix: "refs/tags/", last: 100, orderBy: {field: TAG_COMMIT_DATE, direction: ASC}) {
# or
refs(refPrefix: "refs/tags/", first: 2, orderBy: {field: TAG_COMMIT_DATE, direction: DESC})
```

Comment: I try this in Postman, but it seems there is some syntax error. 
method: post, 
header: Authorization: bearer <my_token>,
json data: ·{
    "query": "query($repoName:sarama, $repoOwner:shopify) { repository(name: $repoName, owner:$repoOwner) {refs(refPrefix: 'refs/tags/', last: 100, orderBy: {field: TAG_COMMIT_DATE, direction: ASC}}}"
}·. 
Could you tell what i am doing wrong? thanks a lot.

Comment: @Rick.X Not sure without seeing the full curl command. Here is an example of working curl calls: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65555312/6309, but storing this complex query in a file could be an easier approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65312822/6309

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this one-liner via an alias short-cut

```
git for-each-ref --sort=-v:refname refs/tags --count 8 --format='%(objectname) %(authordate:short) %(refname) %(align:30) %(authorname) %(end) %(subject)'
```

which sorts, and gives a nice overview of the last tags plus some further info.